# Как заменить (перевести) название ключа в объекте

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, объекты

У меня есть массив объектов.
На фото отображен один из ключей, как мы можем увидеть - вложенные ключи являются некорректными для записи в базу данных и я хотел бы ретранслировать в кириллицу.
Я написал небольшой парсер, но это подходит только для входящего в него текста и никак не получается внедрить его в перебор объектов.

```
function translateToLatin(word){
let converter = {
    'а': 'a',    'б': 'b',    'в': 'v',    'г': 'g',    'д': 'd',
    'е': 'e',    'ё': 'e',    'ж': 'zh',   'з': 'z',    'и': 'i',
    'й': 'y',    'к': 'k',    'л': 'l',    'м': 'm',    'н': 'n',
    'о': 'o',    'п': 'p',    'р': 'r',    'с': 's',    'т': 't',
    'у': 'u',    'ф': 'f',    'х': 'h',    'ц': 'c',    'ч': 'ch',
    'ш': 'sh',   'щ': 'sch',  'ь': '',     'ы': 'y',    'ъ': '',
    'э': 'e',    'ю': 'yu',   'я': 'ya'
};

word = word.toLowerCase();

let answer = '';
for (let i = 0; i < word.length; ++i ) {
    if (converter[word[i]] === undefined){
        answer += word[i];
    } else {
        answer += converter[word[i]];
    }
}

answer = answer.replace(/[^-0-9a-z]/g, '-');
answer = answer.replace(/[-]+/g, '-');
answer = answer.replace(/^\-|-$/g, '');
return answer;
}
```

[image: JSON]

Comment: *"как мы можем увидеть - вложенные ключи являются некорректными для записи в базу данных"* - ничего такого мы не видим.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы создал новый объект и сохранял туда переведённые ключи и их значения.

```js
const obj = {
  'допустим': 'asdasd',
  'какой-то': 1231231,
  'объект123': function() {}
};

let latinObj = {};
for(let key in obj) {
  latinObj[translateToLatin(key)] = obj[key];
}
console.info(latinObj);

function translateToLatin(word) {
  let converter = {
    'а': 'a', 'б': 'b', 'в': 'v', 'г': 'g', 'д': 'd',
    'е': 'e', 'ё': 'e', 'ж': 'zh', 'з': 'z', 'и': 'i',
    'й': 'y', 'к': 'k', 'л': 'l', 'м': 'm', 'н': 'n',
    'о': 'o', 'п': 'p', 'р': 'r', 'с': 's', 'т': 't',
    'у': 'u', 'ф': 'f', 'х': 'h', 'ц': 'c', 'ч': 'ch',
    'ш': 'sh', 'щ': 'sch', 'ь': '', 'ы': 'y', 'ъ': '',
    'э': 'e', 'ю': 'yu', 'я': 'ya'
  };

  word = word.toLowerCase();

  let answer = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; ++i) {
    if (converter[word[i]] === undefined) {
      answer += word[i];
    } else {
      answer += converter[word[i]];
    }
  }

  answer = answer.replace(/[^-0-9a-z]/g, '-');
  answer = answer.replace(/[-]+/g, '-');
  answer = answer.replace(/^\-|-$/g, '');
  return answer;
}
```

---

Так же я бы обновил "транслит" верными данными с этого сайта - [Транслит онлайн переводчик](http://translit-online.ru/)

Comment: я забыл зайти изначально в массив...foreach, следом мне удалось пройтись уже циклом по объектам.
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Вот теперь думаю как можно переводчик сделать так, чтобы мог обратно перевести с переведенного

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что для правильности перевода из латиницы в кириллицу потребуется какой-то алгоритм, для учитывания букв типо "щ" (shch), чтобы не перевести это именно в `схсх`), но это уже другая история. Если мой ответ вам помог, отметьте его галочкой (слева под рейтингом ответа).